# Hot keys to switch between tabs?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know if there´s a shortcut to switch between tabs in Google Spreadsheets?

If you use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd> like in Excel you switch between Chrome or Firefox's tabs instead.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the following short cuts.

### Shotcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd> ==> Move to next sheet (<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> on a Mac)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd>   ==> Move to previous sheet (<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Up arrow</kbd> on a Mac)

### Screenshot

[image]

### Reference

[Keyboard Accelerators](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181110)

Answer (score 10):

On Firefox used <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> to move the worksheet and avoid conflicts with moving the browser tab.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Jacob's correct answer, I noticed there's also a pop-up selector list of all sheets.

This allows "random access" which is quicker if you have a lot of sheets and want to switch between two distant sheets. (Sadly it doesn't have predictive typing for selecting the sheet which I feel it should.)

It's also an easier shortcut for Mac laptops.

```
Navigate spreadsheet

    Display list of sheets  Option + Shift + k . (mac)
    Display list of sheets  Alt + Shift + k      (pc)
```

[Keyboard shortcuts for Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?visit_id=1-636470861235014040-2205709350&hl=en&rd=1)

Answer (score 4):

Here's my approach.  Open a new browser tab for the same google sheet (in Firefox, you can right click on the browser tab and select "Duplicate Tab").  In the new browser tab, select the spreadsheet tab you want to toggle back and forth to.  Now you can use your standard shortcut to toggle between browser tabs.

Answer (score 2):

option up/down arrow works for me on my mac ( as of today )
Before it was the clumsy Cmd + Shift + Fn + Down arrow as described by Jacob.  that combo was unusable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Prayers answered on Mac: To switch between tabs/sheets, you can just use:

### `Option+↑` and `Option+↓`

[image: keyboard shortcuts]

Or `Option+Shift+K` for the dropdown selector