# Keyboard shortcuts to switch Google Sheets tabs in Firefox

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox, windows

This question has been answered, apparently satisfactorily, for presumably non-Firefox browsers (see [Hot keys to switch between tabs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40042/hot-keys-to-switch-between-tabs/113550?noredirect=1#comment100448_113550)).

The accepted solution there is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>pg up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd>. On Firefox, this merely rearranges browser tabs. Would be grateful for an alternative solution (or way to turn off Firefox).

In terms of hopefully disabling the Firefox shortcut that's theoretically overriding the one given in the accepted answer, I can find neither keyconfig nor 'better touch' in the Firefox add-ons; nor can I find anything built into Firefox relating to specifying keyboard shortcuts.

I am running FF Quantum 57.0.4.

Comment: Provided shortcuts work for me in Firefox 56.0 too

Comment: As its not working just in all new FF Quantum, I suggest to log this issue to Google for adding this command to override list

Comment: thanks for the reply. do you know the best way to submit such an issue?

Answer (score 1):

The linked question now has [an answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/129960/14899) that works in Firefox (confirmed in 70 on Windows). Copyediting:

> On Firefox [use] <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> +
>   <kbd>Down</kbd> to [change] worksheet and avoid conflicts with [changing]
>   the browser tab.